# How can I show an image in a NSView using an CGImageRef image

Tags: xcode, nsview, cgimageref

I want to show an image in NSview or in the NSImageView. In my header file I have

```
@interface FVView : NSView
{
    NSImageView *imageView;
}
@end
```

here is what I been trying to do in my implementation file:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    (Here I get an image called fitsImage........ then I do)

    //Here I make the image
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageRetain([fitsImage CGImageScaledToSize:maxSize]);

    NSImage *imageR = [self imageFromCGImageRef:cgImage];
    [imageR lockFocus];

    //Here I have the view context
    CGContextRef ctx = (CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

    //Here I set the via dimensions
    CGRect renderRect = CGRectMake(0., 0., maxSize.width, maxSize.height);

    [self.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    [imageR unlockFocus];

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, renderRect, cgImage);
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
}
```

I don't get anything in the NSview window when I run the script. No errors at all I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. My Xcode version in 5.1.1

I'm trying to learn how to manipulate CGImageRef and view it in a window or nsview.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what exactly your setup is. Drawing an image in a custom view is a separate thing from using an `NSImageView`. Also, a custom view that may (or may not) be layer-backed is different from a layer-hosting view.

You have a lot of the right elements, but they're all mixed up together. In no case do you have to lock focus on an `NSImage`. That's for drawing *into* an `NSImage`. Also, a custom view that subclasses from `NSView` doesn't have to call `super` in its `-drawRect:`. `NSView` doesn't draw anything.

To draw an image in a custom view, try:

```
- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    CGImageRef cgImage = /* ... */;
    NSSize maxSize = /* ... */;
    CGContextRef ctx = (CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGRect renderRect = CGRectMake(0., 0., maxSize.width, maxSize.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, renderRect, cgImage);
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
}
```

If you have an `NSImageView`, then you don't need a custom view or any drawing method or code. Just do the following at the point where you obtain the image or the information necessary to generate it:

```
NSImageView* imageView = /* ... */; // Often an outlet to a view in a NIB rather than a local variable.
CGImageRef cgImage = /* ... */;
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage size:/* ... */];
imageView.image = image;
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

If you're working with a layer-hosting view, you just need to set the `CGImage` as the layer's content. Again, you do this whenever you obtain the image or the information necessary to generate it. It's not in `-drawRect:`.

```
CALayer* layer = /* ... */; // Perhaps someView.layer
CGImageRef cgImage = /* ... */;
layer.contents = (__bridge id)cgImage;
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```